# Understanding bitwise operations - shifting and AND

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, xbee

```
uint8_t payload[] = { 0, 0 };
pin5 = analogRead(A0);
payload[0] = pin5 >> 8 & 0xff;
payload[1] = pin5 & 0xff;
```

This is code from the XBee library published by andrewrapp on GitHub. I was wondering how the bitwise operation worked.
so suppose pin 5 gets an analog value of 256 which as I am using a particle photon board comes in a 12bit format text as 000100000000. so does payload[0] get the last eight bits ie 00000000, or does it get value after shifting ie, 00000001? Also then what becomes the value in payload[1]?

I want to add a 4-bit code of my on using a bitmask to the first four bits in the array followed by the data bits. Can I & payload[1] with a 0X1 to payload[1] for this?

Comment: What is the type of `pin5` and what is the return type of `analogRead` function? Please edit your question to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `payload[0] == 1, [1] == 0` - just as the bits are written in text

Comment: There are plenty of guides about bitwise operations available.   You have given no information about what `pin5` is so, at best, people will have to guess about what the result of using bitwise operations on it is.

Answer (score 0):

The code in your example reverser the content of `pin5`'s two bytes into `payload` array: the most significant byte is placed into `payload[0]` and the least significant byte is placed into `payload[1]`.

If, for example, `pin5` is `0x0A63`, then `payload` would contain `0x63`, `0x0A`.

If `pin5` has a 12-bit value, you can use its four most significant bits to store a four-bit value of your own. To make sure the upper bits are zeroed out, use `0x0F` mask instead of `0xFF`:

```
payload[0] = pin5 >> 8 & 0x0f;
//                         ^
```

Now you can move your data into the upper four bits with `|` operator:

```
payload[0] |= myFourBits << 4;
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to understand what the stated operations do. Let's have a look if we can clarify this, by examining the `pin5` variable and subdividing it into 2 parts:

```
pin5              000100000000
                  MMMMLLLLLLLL
```

`M` = 4 Most significant bits, `L` = 8 Least significant bits

`payload[0]` takes the result of some operations on `pin5`:

```
pin5              000100000000
>> 8              000000000001  Shifts all bits 8 positions to the right
                  00000000MMMM  and fills the left part with zeroes
```

so you have the originally leading 4 bits right-aligned now, on which an additional operation is performed:

```
                  000000000001
& 0xFF            000011111111  Anding with FF
                  000000000001
```

Right-shifting a 12-bits variable by 8 positions leaves 4 significant positions; the leading 8 bits will always be 0. `0xFF` is binary `11111111`, i.e., represents 8 set bits. So what is done here is `And`ing the 4 least significant bits with 8 least significant bits in order to make sure, that the 4 most significant bits get erased.

```
                  00000000xxxx  Potentially set bits (you have 0001)
                  000011111111  & 0xFF
                  00000000xxxx  Result
                      0000xxxx  Storing in 8-bits variable
payload[0] =          00000001  in your case
```

In this case, the `And`ing operation is not useful and a complete waste of time, because `And`ing any variable with `0xFF` does never change its 8 least significant bits in any way, and since the 4 most significant bits are never set anyway, there simply is no point in this operation.

(Technically, because the source is a 12-bits variable (presumably it is a 16 bits variable though, with only 12 significant (relevant) binary digits), `0x0F` would have sufficed for the `And`ing mask. Can you see why? But even this would simply be a wasted CPU cycle.)

`payload[1]` also takes the result of an operation on `pin5`:

```
pin5              MMMMLLLLLLLL  potentially set bits
& 0xFF            000011111111  mask to keep LLLLLLLL only
                  0000LLLLLLLL  result (you have 00000000)
                      xxxxxxxx  Storing in 8-bits variable
payload[1] =          00000000  in your case
```

In this case, Anding with `11111111` makes perfect sense, because it discards `MMMM`, which in your case is `0001`.

So, all in all, your value

```
pin5              000100000000
                  MMMMLLLLLLLL
```

is split such, that `payload[0]` contains `MMMM` (`0001` = decimal 1), and `payload[1]` contains `LLLLLLLL` (`00000000` = decimal 0).

If the input was

```
pin5              101110010001
                  MMMMLLLLLLLL
```

instead, you would find in `payload[0]`: `1011` (decimal 8+2+1 = 11), and in `payload[1]`: `10010001` (decimal 128+16+1 = 145).

You would interpret this result as decimal 11 * 256 + 145 = 2961, the same result you obtain when converting the original 101110010001 from binary into decimal, for instance using `calc.exe` in Programmer mode (`Alt+3`), if you are using Windows.

Likewise, your original data is being interpreted as 1 * 256 + 0 = 256, as expected.